# How to Update the record if the time difference between existing record has been more then time minutes?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, timestamp-arithmetic

I have a column "STARTDATETIME" with datatype TimeStamp. Now i want to check that if existing record time is 10 minutes more then the current time then i will update the status of that row.

```
String updateData = "update test_bank set status = 'FAILED' where  '"CurrentDateTime()+"' > startdatetime";
```

Comment: I am using Oracle DBMS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add the interval as:

```
SYSTIMESTAMP + INTERVAL '10' MINUTE
```

For example,

```
SQL> SELECT SYSTIMESTAMP tm , SYSTIMESTAMP + INTERVAL '10' MINUTE new_tm FROM dual;

TM                                            NEW_TM
--------------------------------------------- --------------------------------------
19-JUN-15 06.00.23.284000 PM +05:30           19-JUN-15 06.10.23.284000000 PM +05:30

SQL>
```

In the above output, 10 minutes are added to timestamp which made `06.00` to `06.10`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using mysql then there is a function called [TIMESTAMPDIFF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) that you can use to calculate the difference between two timestamps.

```
TIMESTAMPDIFF(unit,datetime_expr1,datetime_expr2)
```

Related answer for Oracle:

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/53924/how-do-i-get-the-difference-in-minutes-from-2-timestamp-columns

Comment: I am using Oracle DBMS

Comment: @user3548196 check the link in my udpated answer for Oracle